# Why does Rust not infer this closure's return type?

Tags: rust, type-inference

The Rust compiler is usually able to infer the type of an expression that is returned from a closure:

```
fn main() {
    let a_closure = |num|{
        num+1.0
    };
    println!("{}", a_closure(1.0));
}
```

But the compiler is unable to infer the type when I define the same closure [using a `return` statement](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d9121e705058ec400a9ff908e0c55fa):

```
fn main() {
    let a_closure = |num|{
        return num+1.0
    };
    println!("{}", a_closure(1.0));
}

/*
    error[E0308]: mismatched types
     --> src/main.rs:3:9
      |
    3 |         return num+1.0
      |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found `f64`
*/
```

I'm surprised that Rust can't infer the type here: is it possible to use a `return` statement in a closure without preventing the compiler from inferring its return type?

Comment: Interestingly, adding the type annotation `num: f64` fixes compilation when `return` is used. Lack of inference could be filed as a bug or feature request for the compiler. However, the confusing error message might be considered a bug. The message "expected `()`, found `f64`" doesn't seem appropriate for the example, and the annotation `num: f64` doesn't look like something that should affect it.

Comment: The message is appropriate for the error, it says that rustc inferred the return type as `()` but we're returning a `f64`. Notice how `fn foo() { 1.0f64 }` triggers the exact same error message (except *it* suggests adding a return type).

Comment: Calling `a_closure(1.0f64)` also fixes the issue.

Comment: Adding an explicit return type to the closure also fixes the error: `|num| -> f64 { return num+1.0 }`

Comment: @Masklinn The error message would be appropriate if the compiler's inference were supported by a constraint that would require `()` to be the return type, but that's just not the case here. This is why I consider the message confusing, or at least misleading: it seems to imply such a constraint where it doesn't exist. Also, the difference between `foo` and `return foo;` (the final semicolon doesn't make a difference) seems like a straight-up bug.

Comment: @user4815162342 the bug is that rustc infers the return value as `()`, the error message directly follows from that. The bug is not in the error message, it is in and of itself correct.

Comment: @Masklinn You're right. I misread your original "message is appropriate for the error" as stating that the message correctly describes insufficient inference, which is not in itself a compiler issue. The error I would expect to see here is "error[E0282]: type annotations needed".

Comment: I've now reported [an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/81036).

Answer (score -2):

This is due to the lack of a semicolon. When you have no semicolon, the last expression is returned, and this last expression is `return num + 1.0`. Since a return statement makes the program jump somewhere, else, it's value can be anything, for example:

```
fn main() {
    let a: String = return;
}
```

However, if the compiler sees no direct type assigned to it, it will pick the type `()` as the value of the return statement.

So what happened is:

1. The compiler sees the last expression in the closure, and assigns it the type `()` by default.
2. The compiler then sees an explicit return inside the closure, which returns the type `i32`.

So since there are two attempts to return from the closure, and they each return different types, that's a type mismatch.

Comment: That was my first guess too, but it's wrong: adding the missing semicolon doesn't fix the error.

Comment: This fails to explain why annotating **any** of the numbers in the code, `return num + 1.0f64` or `a_closure(1.0f64)` or `|num: f64| { ... }` will cause the error to go away, and why this error only seems to manifest itself for numerical type inference (try using a string-specific method; nothing goes wrong)